# Why does GetAsync return nil?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have tried to fix this script, but i cannot.
It is the primary script which maintains most server side stuff.
I tried to make an DataStore handler, but it returns nil.
Code:

```lua
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DrawingData = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("DrawingData")
rep.SendToRandom.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,data)
    
end)
rep.LoadFromDatastore.OnServerInvoke = function(plr,...)
    local success,gotten =pcall(DrawingData.SetAsync,DrawingData,...)
    if not success then
        gotten = {}
        warn("Failure with DataStore get, replacing with placeholder.")
    end
    return gotten
end
rep.SaveToDatastore.OnServerInvoke =function(plr,data:string)
    local a = {DrawingData:GetAsync("GM")}
    local gotten = tonumber(a[1])
    DrawingData:SetAsync(tostring(gotten + 1),data)
    DrawingData:SetAsync("GM",tostring(gotten + 1))
    return gotten + 1
end
```

Output:

```
Failure with DataStore get, replacing with placeholder.
```

Saving works, and loading should work.
But, loading doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `SetAsync` and `GetAsync` without actual UserId to store it to, you should save and load the data to a UserId unless the data is meant to be accessed by everyone (which I do NOT recommend).

From what I can tell you are trying to save data for individual players, but you are storing their data or their data I suppose to a singular DataStore, which will only make it more difficult for the game to load once it is prompted to load again.

Here is what I wrote based on what I believe you are trying to accomplish

```lua
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DrawingData = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("DrawingData")

rep.LoadFromDatastore.OnServerInvoke = function(plr,...)
    local success, response = pcall(function(...)
        return DrawingData:SetAsync(plr.UserId, ...)
    end, ...)
    if success ~= true or type(response) ~= "table" or table.getn(response) == 0 then
        return {}, type(response) == "string" and warn(response)
    end
    return response
end

rep.SaveToDatastore.OnServerInvoke =function(plr, data)
    local success, response = pcall(function()
        return DrawingData:GetAsync(plr.UserId)
    end)
    if success ~= true or type(response) ~= "table" or table.getn(response) == 0 then
        response = {}
    end
    table.insert(response, data)
    local success, response
    while success ~= true do
        success, response = pcall(function()
            return DrawingData:SetAsync(plr.UserId, response)
        end)
        if success ~= true then
            warn(response)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: No, that is not what i want to accomplish, i want for everyone that has an save code to be able to load an drawing

Comment: I want players to have multiple drawings, and they can access it with an save code